# Logistic regression (reciprocal of logistic regression coefficient interpretation)

Tags: logistic-regression

Suppose if a dependent variable is having a disease (1) and not having a disease (0). similarly , independent variable is smoking and not smoking. here , not smoking as reference group.
Again, if logistic coefficient of smoking is - 0.3.
odd ratio = exp (-0.3) = 0.74
Can we interpret it as , reciprocal of odd ratio= 1/0.74 = 1.34 ..
Smoker have 1.34 times odd of not having disease than non smoker. or
is it " Non smoker have 1.34 times odd of having disease than smoker"
is both interpretation correct or not ? I am just confused.